# Не показывать клавиатуру при заходе на активити

Tags: android, клавиатура, activity

Скачиваю данные с сервера и вывожу их списком. Над списком есть поле для поиска по списку. Проблема в том, что при заходе в эту активити сразу же вылезает клавиатура. 
Как сделать так, чтобы клавиатура не вылезала?

Answer (score 2):

Вот решение, которое помогло:

```
<activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

...

Comment: да оно, его имел ввиду, описался) поправил свой ответ

Answer (score 0):

Напиши в файле **`AndroidManifest.xml`** для данной активити свойство **`windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden`"**, тогда при первом запуске активити клавиатуре не будет показываться

Comment: Прописал это дело, но эффекта не дало. Все-равно клавиатура вылезает..

Comment: Как только вхожу в активити, вижу как сразу окно для набора текста становится активным, после чего и вылезает клавиатура...